# How can I smooth or add loop cut without putting it between faces one by one?

Tags: modeling

[image: I want to add loop cut in each faces without putting it one by one]

I want to add loop cut in each faces without putting it one by one. How can I do it?

Comment: Please don't talk in all caps, it's generally considered shouting.

Answer (score 2):

To add multiple loop cuts at the same time, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to enable the loop cut tool, then scroll up/down to increase/decrease the number of cuts.

*Edit*:

Use *Subdivide* rather than loop cut. Select all the faces, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, then select subdivide. You'll end up with an extra loop parallel to the circle, so select that loop, and *Dissolve Edges.*

[image]

Comment: But it will only add loop cut in a single face

Comment: Ohhh ok, I didn't understand the question properly at first. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: thank you so much ! this help a lot